# How can i render specific object prop on page after selected opinion fire onChange() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I will simplify as code is bit huge.

My pizzas has arrays for size and price. When user select size i want to update price, problem is that pizzas are mapping from cart... brainstorming for half a day and stuck. please help.

```
{cart.products.map((product,index) => (
   
          <Product key={index}>
            <ProductDetail>
              <Image src={product?.img} />
                  <Details>
                    <ProductName>
                      <b>Pizza:</b> {product?.name}
                    </ProductName>
                    
                  <PizzaSelect  onChange={handleChange} > //do i need value here?
                    
                      {product.size.map((size,i)=>(
                      <FilterSizeOption  key={i} value={product.price[i]} >{size}</FilterSizeOption>))}
                  </PizzaSelect>


                  </Details>        
             </ProductDetail>      
              <PriceDetail>
                  <ProductPrice>
                   €{product.price[0]} //problem
                  </ProductPrice>
                  <RemoveItemButton onClick={()=>emptyCartByProduct(product)}>delete</RemoveItemButton>
              </PriceDetail>
             
          </Product> ))}
```

my handleChange

```
const handleChange = (e) =>{

 console.log(e.target.value) 
 
}
```

i did get price for specific pizza.

in database i have `size:[small,normal,big]`
also for price `price:[2,3,4]`

on first render all is fine. Maybe to create some map?

- used styled-components

Answer (score 0):

for now i have this solution:

```
 const handleChange = (e) =>{
const target=e.target.value.split(",")

 document.getElementById(target[1]).innerText = '€'+target[0]
}
```

and then in render:

```
{cart.products.map((product,prodi) => (
   
          <Product key={prodi}>
            <ProductDetail>
              <Image src={product?.img} />
                  <Details>
                    <ProductName>
                      <b>Pizza:</b> {product?.name}
                    </ProductName>
                    
                  <FilterSize  onChange={handleChange} >
                    
                      {product.size.map((size,i)=>(
                      <FilterSizeOption  key={i} value={[product.price[i],product._id]} >{size}</FilterSizeOption>))}
                  </FilterSize>


                  </Details>        
             </ProductDetail>      
              <PriceDetail>
                  <ProductPrice id={product._id} >
                   €{product.price[0]}
                  </ProductPrice>
                  <RemoveItemButton onClick={()=>emptyCartByProduct(product)}>delete</RemoveItemButton>
              </PriceDetail>
             
          </Product> ))}`
```

can someone provide better solution?